# How to pick capacitor dimensions

Tags: capacitor, design

What are the tradeoffs and design considerations for capacitor dimensions? Specifically, I need to select 2 electrolytic capacitors (C2 and C3) for a car voltage (noisy 12V) to 5V converter.

Here's the circuit:
[image: power circuit]

How would I pick a capacitor from this datasheet?
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/420/al-kze-e-140701-514740.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that affects capacitor size is energy storage capability and given that energy stored is proportional to voltage squared, THE most important factor that determines size is the voltage rating.

So you figure out the necessary voltage rating and from the datasheet you pick the size that has the required capacitance at that voltage rating.

If you want to take account of load dumping (battery disconnection and reconnection whilst running) you need to consider this: -

[image]

Yes, it says 100V so you might wish to consider this circuit from TI: -

[image]

So, if you are going to choose capacitors that are able to withsatnd a load dump you need to choose types that have a voltage rating greater than 100V and, unfortunately, your linked data sheet does not appear to cover.

Comment: D3 is already providing transient over voltage suppression (600W).

I was looking for why an explanation of why pick a 5mm diameter capacitor vs a 10mm or 16mm diameter capacitor if the capacitance is the same.

Comment: The thing that affects capacitor size is energy storage capability and given that energy stored is proportional to voltage squared, THE most important factor that determines size is the voltage rating.

Comment: I see. So you figure out the necessary voltage rating and from the datasheet you pick the size that has the required capacitance at that voltage rating. Thanks!

Comment: That's the way to do it.